# Indexing relationships in Neo4j using Scala

Tags: java, scala, neo4j, graph-databases

Say that there is a relationship between 2 nodes as below

```
start --> "follows" --> end
```

I want to create an index named "Relations" and add the above relation to the index. How do I do that in Scala or in Java?

I tried doing it this way :

```
override def NodeIndexConfig = ("Relations", Some(Map("provider" -> "lucene", "type" -> "fulltext")))::NIL
    val rel_name = group+"_Voteup"
    val relation = user_node --> rel_name --> item_node

    val Relation_Index = getNodeIndex("Relations").get
    val rel_value = user_id+item_id+rel_name
    Relation_Index += (relation,"rel_id",rel_value)
```

But, am getting Type mismatch error.

Comment: Have a look at [this example code](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/master/community/embedded-examples/src/main/java/org/neo4j/examples/EmbeddedNeo4jWithIndexing.java). I hope it will help

Comment: In that example he just indexed the nodes. But, in my case in need to index the relationships between the nodes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use the relation index instead of the node index, like

```
override def RelationIndexConfig = ("Relations", Some(Map("provider" -> "lucene", "type" -> "fulltext")))::Nil
val rel_name = group+"_Voteup"
val relation = user_node --> rel_name --> item_node

val Relation_Index = getRelationIndex("Relations")
val rel_value = user_id+item_id+rel_name
Relation_Index.foreach(_ += (relation,"rel_id",rel_value))
```

NOTE: I removed the `index.get` call and used a "safer" `foreach` call on the optional value.

Comment: Changed override def NodeIndexConfig to override def RelationIndexConfig and it worked. Thanks :)

Comment: You're right, I missed that. I'll update the answer to the correct method.